# Changing TOR identity in R without Privoxy

Tags: r, tor, rcurl

I am using this script to connect to TOR from R (windows) and it works fine:

```
library(RCurl)
curl = getCurlHandle()
curlSetOpt(proxy="127.0.0.1:9150", proxytype=5, curl=curl)
print(getURL("http://ifconfig.me/ip", curl=curl))
```

There must be a way to change the TOR identity without using Privoxy.
Somehow, I would have to pass the "signal NEWNYM" otpion to the curl handle. I looked for the getCurlOptionsConstants()

```
sort(names(getCurlOptionsConstants()))
```

but I could not find a solution. I tried

```
curl = getCurlHandle()
curlSetOpt(proxy="127.0.0.1:9150", proxytype=5, 
       telnetoptions = "signal newnym",
       curl=curl)
print(getURL("http://ifconfig.me/ip", curl=curl))
```

but it does not change the IP...